# Markers Display on Leaflet but Not on Mapbox in React Native App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mapbox

` I'm developing a React Native application where I need to display markers on a map. I'm fetching these markers from a database and successfully displaying them on a Leaflet map. However, when I try to display the same markers on a Mapbox map, they do not appear.

What I've tried:

Ensured that the markers' data fetched from the database is correctly formatted and accessible in the component where I'm trying to display them on the Mapbox map.
Checked the Mapbox and React Native Mapbox GL documentation to ensure I'm using the correct method for adding markers.
Looked for any errors or warnings in the console that might indicate what's going wrong but found none.
Expected Behavior:

Markers should display on the Mapbox map similarly to how they display on the Leaflet map.

Actual Behavior:

Markers do not appear on the Mapbox map, despite no errors being logged to the console.

Code Snippets:

Mao.js (For fetching markers data)

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
 import { View } from 'react-native';
 import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
 import { styles } from '../styles';
 import { fetchMarkers } from '../api/api';


      const MapScreen = () => {
      const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
      const webViewRef = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
 const loadMarkers = async () => {
  try {
    const fetchedMarkers = await fetchMarkers();
    console.log('Fetched markers:', fetchedMarkers);
    setMarkers(fetchedMarkers);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching markers:', error);
  }
   };

   loadMarkers();
   }, []);

 const injectedJavaScript = `
 (function() {
  window.addMarkers(${JSON.stringify(markers)});
    })();
  `;



  return (
   // In MapScreen component
   <View style={styles.container}>
   <WebView
    key={markers.length} // Add this line. It forces WebView to re-render when markers change.
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={require('../assets/html/mapbox.html')}
    style={styles.mapView}
    injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
     startInLoadingState={true}
    onLoadEnd={() => {
      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(injectedJavaScript);
    }}
    ref={webViewRef}
   onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
   const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
     console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
    }}
     />
   </View>

     );
   };

    export default MapScreen;`
```

mapbox.html

```
          `<!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
          <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8' />
           <title>Mapbox Map</title>
           <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
          <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
          <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
         <style>
         body, html, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
         </style>
       </head>
        <body>
         <div id='map'></div>
       <script>
       mapboxgl.accessToken = 'i have token for here ';

       var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
         center: [-74.5, 40], // Starting center coordinates [longitude, latitude]
         zoom: 9 // Starting zoom level
         });
 
          // Function to add markers to the map
        function addMarkers(markers) {
           markers.forEach(function(marker) {
           new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([marker.lon, marker.lat]).addTo(map);
         });
         }

         // Inform React Native when the map is loaded
         map.on('load', function() {
         if(window.ReactNativeWebView) {
          window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('Map is loaded');
           }
          });
             </script>
          </body>
          </html>`
```

Environment:
(All latest versions)
React Native
React
Mapbox GL
Leaflet

Question:

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insight into why the markers would display on Leaflet but not on Mapbox within a React Native application? Any suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

What I've tried:

Ensured that the markers' data fetched from the database is correctly formatted and accessible in the component where I'm trying to display them on the Mapbox map.
Checked the Mapbox and React Native Mapbox GL documentation to ensure I'm using the correct method for adding markers.
Looked for any errors or warnings in the console that might indicate what's going wrong but found none.
Expected Behavior:

Markers should display on the Mapbox map similarly to how they display on the Leaflet map.

Actual Behavior:

Markers do not appear on the Mapbox map, despite no errors being logged to the console.
`